# Understanding "android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1"

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to work with an OEM Android manufacturer to decipher an issue.  We don't know if the error is in our app or in their OS (Android 9).  I feel I cannot rely on the manufacturer 100% and so I need to be able to understand some of the system log files.

I could not find anything on the above log statement.  I understand what it literally means, that Android could not retrieve the current memory being used, but what is the context?  Does that mean for the system?  For the app only?  Does that mean memory there is not enough memory?  Any info would be helpful.